# How can I properly QoS streaming services on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, openwrt, qos

I'm going to start by explaining my naivete, I'm not sure, if netflix via a web browser uses the same protocol (http?) as netflix via a smart tv, for example. I'm using OpenWRT 14.07 currently, and am using the `luci-app-qos` and `qos-scripts` packages.

I would like to QoS video streaming appropriately.

How can I detect them? what target type (express/priority) do they need to be to be smooth?. How can I ensure they are a lower priority, than say normal web browsing. Is it possible for this to work for all video streaming? or do I have to prioritize each service individually (for example I probably wouldn't *bother* with ustream, but if I could get it prioritized the same automagically). Services I'm most concerned about are netflix, amazon, hulu, and youtube.

Comment: OpenWRT does not have a very effective QoS implementation. Configuring it is kind of a stab in the dark unless you know enough about the packets to hand sort them. If a build is available for your router I would highly recommend flashing Tomato instead, specifically a [shibby](http://tomato.groov.pl/) remix. If not available, DDWRT is available for more hardware and has better QoS that OpenWRT (but not nearly as good or easy to configure as Tomoto's.